# Generate Javabean from XML input

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I need to create a javabean from xml input.There wont be any irregularities in the xml input which I give.
I know stuffs like JAXB and Apache XMLbeans work.

But here I need to autogenerate the JAVAbeanclass without using its xsd.
In short when I give any xml inputs the outputs have to be the pojo classes generated.

Any inputs for this???

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution for that is develop your own DOM (if there is many items on the XML) or SAX (if there is a lot of items) parser.
DOM takes more memory so it is not recommended for XML with many nodes (and/or many attributes).

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools like **wsgen** to generate class files from a service.

Here is a example,

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-wsgen-tool-example/